# RoutingError and no controller or action details given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, routes, mailer

I have a separate class which organises all aspects of creating accounts based on prerequisite data (i.e. if the user already exists, rather than create a user, instead add this data to that user account). Both of these situations then send an email to the user, notifying them to provide required information for their account (new user) or simply informing them that X data has been added to their account. These transactional emails are managed using Postage App.

When working in development locally, each aspect of the system works as intended, and the appropriate email is sent in each situation, however on the demo server (located on Heroku) a strange issue occurs, namely a RoutingError is thrown, with the message being "No route matches {}" (no controller or action is listed).

Having launched the rails console inside Heroku, I tried checking this route and no error is thrown.

Here is the snippet of the Heroku server logs during this process:

```
2012-08-04T01:07:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/user_mailer/new_user_email.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_user_mailer_new_user_email_html_haml___1192864641417349048_59959220'
2012-08-04T01:07:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/lib/user_generator.rb:70:in `send_user_email'
2012-08-04T01:07:09+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {}):
2012-08-04T01:07:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:13:in `new_user_email'
2012-08-04T01:07:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/details_controller.rb:62:in `finalise'
2012-08-04T01:07:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/lib/user_generator.rb:36:in `generate_user_details'
```

After this occurs, PostageApp then sends the alternate email instead to the users email address.

The code which controls this being:

```
 def send_user_email(is_new)
    if is_new
      UserMailer.new_user_email(@user).deliver
    else
      UserMailer.confirm_details_email(@user, @details).deliver
    end 
  end
```

My primary question would be what could cause Heroku to produce this sort of RoutingError (which does not occur when running the code locally) - after which is there any reason why PostageApp would send a separate template instead of that intended?

---

EDIT: Reason for alternative email being sent was the 500 error produced caused the callback to retry, resulting in the details being re-added to the user and the second email being sent.

My question is now what would potentially cause a routing error to occur when the helper method called works on the server in the console (exactly as it would have been displayed in the email)?

Comment: Does this line: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {})` indicate that an empty hash is being passed as a paremeter? If there's no argument there won't be any matches.

Comment: That's usually the result of a `link_to('Label', { })` or an equivalent with an empty hash sent in as the second argument. Using named routes could avoid this.

Comment: I've only used named routes, however an issue seems to occur somewhat related to this whereby the host cannot be resolved between Heroku and PostageApp (it resolves to something like app123123123@heroku.com).